# Killing a thread with a socket in it (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am pretty new at this.I am trying to build a server(chat server)
 Sorry for presenting such a messing code. 
There are alot of things that i am going to change about this code. 
but as of now i just need help with one thing:

when i start let say more then one cleints on this ...and then just close the client i get this message:

Unhandled exception in thread started by

i have tryed to kill the thread as you can see in many places in this code. but i don't know what i am doing wrong ..
i am new at this.
any syggestions on what i should do ?

```
#encoding: utf-8

import socket, random, time, thread, errno, traceback

print socket.gethostname()
print "current machines IP address: "+socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

host ="10.0.0.1"# raw_input("IP: ")
# = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 12345

print host

conn_list =[None]*10
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(10)

print "connected..\n\n\n\n"

def recv(conn):
    while True:
        try:
            message = conn.recv(1024)
            if "MESG" == message[1:5]:
                message = message[6:].split(':')
                name = str(conn)
                conn_number = conn_list.index(conn)
                conn_name = str(conn_number)
                message = message[2]
                reciever = message[0:1]
                reciever = int(reciever)
                for conn in conn_list:
                    if reciever == conn_list.index(conn):
                        conn.send(message)
                        print "Connection   "+conn_name+"  ----->  "+str(reciever)+"   :"+message+"\n"
                        #conn = findTheRightConnection(conn_list, conn_number)
                        break
                    else:
                        pass

        except ValueError:
            print "ValueError by %s" % (str(conn))
            print conn.send("\nOpps you are not typing the correct connection number infront  your message!")

        except IOError:
            bye(conn,conn_list)
            print"Going to try to kill the thread here "
            thread.quit()
            thread.isAlive()
            print "Still alive..."

        except socket.error, v:
            errorcode=v[0]
            bye(conn,conn_list)
            print"Going to try to kill the thread or here"
            thread.quit()
            thread.isAlive()
            print "Still alive..."


        except Exception, e:
            traceback.print_exc()

        finally:
            thread.isAlive()
            print"\nChanging the conn back to what it was... "
            conn = findTheRightConnection(conn_list, conn_number)


def handle_connection(conn):
    try:
        recv(conn)

    except socket.error, v:
        errorcode=v[104]
        bye(conn)


def bye(conn,conn_list):
    i= 0
    print "bye"
    connectionName = str(conn_list.index(conn))
    conn.close
    conn_list = conn_list
    print conn_list
    for element in conn_list:
        if element == conn:
            conn_list[i] = None
            break
        i += i
        print "Connection number "+connectionName+" is terminated"
        print conn_list

        return "Connection Terminated"


def welcome(conn,conn_list):
    i = 0
    for element in conn_list:
        if element == None:
            conn_list[i] = conn
            print "Connection added in the conn_list on the slot %d" % (i)
            print conn_list
            return conn_list

        else:
            i = i+1
            pass
    print "The server if full! No more space left"
    return conn_list


def findTheRightConnection(conn_list, number):
    for conn in conn_list:
        if number == conn_list.index(conn):
            return conn
        else:
            pass

        print "\nSomthing went wrong while trying to find the right connection in the method findTheRightConnection()"
        return


while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    conn_list = welcome(conn,conn_list)
    print "Got connection from : "+str(addr[0])+" by connection number: "+str(conn_list.index(conn))+"\n\n\n\n"     
    msg = "Welcome to the server!"
    conn.send(":INFO:"+str(int(time.time()))+":"+str(len(msg))+":"+msg)
    thread.start_new_thread(handle_connection, (conn,))
```

Comment: Just close the socket and then kill the thread.

Comment: Hi Bajit, maybe if you post the actual stacktrace? There are lots of places where things might go wrong. Your code could be radically simplified by creating a connection class, maybe using a dictionary instead of a list to store your connections in... You could look at the generalised aysnc socket server that I use for small servers here: https://github.com/aychedee/octopus/blob/master/octopus/server.py

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having trouble creating a instant messaging program in Python, you might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13783740/216356) to another question.

- **Simple_Server.py** is a minimal server implementation. A far more complex server with a variety of features can be provided on request. The complex server supports authentication, friends, private messaging, channels, filters, math evaluation, and admin controls.
- **MultichatClient.py** is a port of a Java program written by a teacher from a networking class. The program must be run from the command line, and it must be given the server as an argument. You can use either the server's name on the network or its IP address.
- **Simple_Client.pyw** is a more complicated client that does not require being started from the command line. When it starts, it will ask for server's name and try connecting to it while showing a progress dialog. The program will automatically try logging any errors to a file.
- **affinity.py** is required for **threadbox.py** to run. (runs code on a specific thread regardless of origin)
- **threadbox.py** is required for **safetkinter.py** to run. (metaclass clones classes to run using affinity)
- **safetkinter.py** is required for **Simple_Client.pyw** to run. (makes tkinter safe to use with threads)